# Simple Workflow register a new version

Tags: amazon-swf

I changed the timeout of an activity. In aws doc, it says I must register a new version of that type in this case. But how to let the execution use the new version?

Answer (score 0):

The decider schedules an activity using [ScheduleActivityTask](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ScheduleActivityTaskDecisionAttributes.html) decision. Which requires activity version to be specified. So you have to change your decider code to use the new version of the activity.

If you are using the flow framework just change the activity version (in the [@Activitie](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/annotations.html#annotations-activities)s annotation for the [Java version of the framework](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/welcome.html)) and redeploy both the activity and the decider code. More complex upgrade scenarious can be supported through  overriding activity version during invocation by passing [ActivitySchedulingOptions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/clients.html) parameter.